# Data Removal Standards

Tags: standards, erase

I want to write an application that removes data from a hard drive. Are there any standards that I need to adhere to which will ensure that my software removes at least the bare minimum, or should I just use off the shelf software? If so any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think any "standard" you may encounter won't be any less science fiction or science mysticism than anything you come up with yourself. Basically, as long as you *physically* overwrite the data (even just once), there's no commercial forensic service that - even in the face of any amount of money you throw at them - will claim to be able to recover your data.

(Any "overwrite 35 times with rotating bit patterns" advice may have been true for coarsely spaced magnetic tapes in the 1970s, but it is entirely irrelevant for contemporary hard disks).

The far more important problem you have to solve is *how* to overwrite data physically. This is essentially impossible through any sort of application or even OS programming, and you'll have to find a way to talk to the hardware properly and get a reliable confirmation that the location you intended to write to has indeed be written to, and that there aren't any relocations of the clusters in question to other parts of the disk that might leak the data.

So in essence this is a very low-level question that'll probably have you pouring over your hard disk manufacturer's manuals quite a bit if you want a genuine solution.

Comment: so you suggest just overwriting the data just a single time is sufficient enough to remove business data from a drive? What makes this any more secure than doing a windows format for example

Comment: Windows format may not overwrite any given piece of data at all. Typically formatting just writes a bit of indexing data at sparse locations. Physical overwriting is the least you *have* to do, but I claim that it's also the most you *need* to do. It's just pretty tricky to get it right!

Answer (score 0):

Please define "data removal". Is this scrubbing in order to make undeletions impossible; or simply deletion of data ?

It is common to write over a file several times with a random bitpattern, if one wants to make sure it cannot be recovered. Due to the analog nature of the magnetic bit patterns, it might be possible to recover overwritten data in some circumstances.

Under all circumstances a normal file system delete operation will be revertable in most cases. When you delete a file (using a normal file system delete operation), you remove the file allocation table entry, not the data.

Comment: the idea of making data non recoverable

Answer (score 0):

There are standards... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure

You don't give any details so it is hard to tell whether they apply to your situation... Deleting a file with OS built-in file deletion can be almost always reverted... OTOH formatting a drive (NOT quick format) is usually ok except when you deal with sensitive data (like data from clients, patients, finance etc. or some security relevant stuff) then the above mentioned standards which usually use differents amounts/rounds/patterns of overwriting the data so make it nearly impossible to revert the deletion... in really really sensitive cases you first use the best of these methods, then format the drive, then use that method again and then destroy the drive physically (which in fact means real destruction, not only removing the electronics or similar!).

The best way to avoid all this hassle is to plan for this kind of thing and to use strong proven full-disk-encryption (with a key NOT stored on the drive electronics or media!)... this way you can easily just format the drive (NOT quick) and then sell it for example... since any strong encryption will look like "random data" is (if implemented correctly) absolutely useless without the key(s).